# Draw trail behind player when its not moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

My game main player is sometime moving and some time in game play remain at same position. I have added trail renderer as child gameobject but when player is moving only that time trail get drawn as player stop its movement trail slowly become invisible.

This thing I don't want, I want always at least some trail get drawn with player. But how to do this?

Comment: Then you're not looking for a trail renderer, that is literally what a trail renderer does(Hence its name)  You could if you wanted use code to check if your character is moving, and if he isnt add to the trail renderer.

Comment: So you want the trail to persist when he stops?

Comment: @KYL3R yes I want to persist trail when player stop movement...

Answer (score 0):

To make the trail persist, increase the "How long does the trail take to fade out." [docs - trailRenderer time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer-time.html)

Now the trail stays longer/forever. It won't vanish when you move a lot, too.

Maybe you want distance-vanish **instead** of time vanish.

You can iterate over the points and compare distances. then dissolve them.

Comment: I want to do this game kind of implementation - in this if we are not moving our finger then also trail render get drawn always - I was making something similar in game play but with landscape mode - https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mmm+fingers+2

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a particle system with the trail renderer module activate. For the effect you showed you could make it sending a single particle in the downward direction and using a trail to follow it.

Edit: Here is an image showing where the module is. You will need to tweak a little while to get your desired effect but it looks doable. Have fun!

[image]

Comment: whether particle system can able to draw trail?

Comment: I edited the answer to help you a little more to find the trails module.

Comment: Okay let me try with above thing and reply back to you - thanks @Adrian Srgo for your help

Comment: Note: I suggest to use "Emission: Distance" and also check "world space". But I don't see the advantage over the TrailRenderer, depending on the desired fancy-ness of the trail.

Comment: @KYL3R you are completely right. But i figured out by looking at the example he provided that the trail mostly goes in the downward direction so it could be easier to mimic by using a particle system in that direction. Could be a wrong approach thou and a trail renderer could reach a better outcome.

Comment: Creating a trail using Particle System's Trail component is too tough, any help with properties settings....